# Adding plywood flooring to attic

Tags: attic, plywood

*I'm in the US.*

I'm looking into adding a plywood "floor" to an attic above a garage. I'd also like to be able to walk on the plywood.

The wooden beams that are already there are 1.75" (measuring tape), and there's about 22.5" (ish) of spacing *between* the existing beams. There's also a few "flat" beams that I haven't measured.

Here's a photo of it*:

[image: Photo of attic]

What size/thickness of plywood (or OSB?) should I get? I'd like to be able to walk on it and store items on it.

Comment: we usually do One question/One answer

Comment: @Ruskes Is that better?

Comment: OSB is good and not so expensive as plywood. 1/2 inch would be enough, it might flex but will hold. 3/4 you can dance on it, It is all up to your budget and how much load will you be putting on it (storage)

Comment: Are you in California or an area with similarly mild climate?

Answer (score 5):

It's very, very likely that your garage roof structure is not designed to support any additional loads on the lower members (truss chords or rafter ties. Truss chords in this case, evidently from what can be seen in the pictures.)

So, decking it over with (typically) 3/4" plywood or OSB and storing stuff on it *might not be a good idea.* 3/4" is a good guess, what you specifically need if your truss is built to support a floor load is a sheet **rated XX/24** [span](https://www.apawood.org/apa-trademark) (xx being the span as roofing and a number we don't care about here, so it could be 48 or 32 or whatever, 24 being the span you need for flooring use since 22.5" between is 24" on center for stock 2x material.)

In all likelihood, merely putting the sheet goods on the bottom chords will be exceeding the load your garage roof truss was built to take there, much less storing stuff on them. You should run down what your truss was actually rated for from plans or other documents before piling a bunch of stuff on it and possibly breaking your roof structure. It appears to already be carrying a drywall ceiling below the chords.